# Dagger 2 multiprocess dependencies

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an `ApplicationComponent` which provides access to my repositories : 
LocationRepository, PlaylistRepository, ...

These repositories are all `@Singleton`.
So far so good.

My issue is that I need to access to one of these repositories (LocationRepository) from a Service in another process.

I could just do `new LocationRepository(params)` in that service (and I do need another instance since the service lifecycle is independent from the app's one) but that's not very safe.
If I change how the service is created in dagger, I could forget to update the service as well.

So is there a way to have a part of a component (here the LocationService) declared separately and instantiated the same way in two different component ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to ensure that the definition (and instantiation logic) of your `LocationRepository` is identical across two processes.

If that's the case, you could always pull it in to its own library module, and have both processes take that module as a dependency.  You could even put a `@Component` interface there, too.

I wouldn't recommend it.

You would end up with two instances of the same singleton.  This is unavoidable because processes are isolated from each other, and do not share memory.  Each has its own VM.  This would result in hard-to-debug data races, as both processes read from and write to a single resource.

It makes more sense to me that one process would "own" it, and the other process would access it via inter-process communication, e.g. via an AIDL interface, like the Google Play Services clients.

I imagine that one process hosts a long-lived Service, and the other hosts your UI.  In this case, your Service is a natural owner of the singleton, and your UI process would use an implementation of the repository that communicates with the service.  This could even participate in injection; make a module that `@Provide`s a LocationRepository, and give it a bound service connection.

This is all really high-level; I hope it makes sense and is helpful.  Happy to provide more detail if I can!

Comment: I mostly want to know how to express this shared definition in two different injections :-)  .  You are right though, the 2 instances would be independent with possible data races. In my specific use case it is not really an issue (I have an UI which does read/write and an IntentService with only read access).   It would make sense to move the repo to a separate process altogether though.

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentA.java`

```
@Component(modules = ModuleA.class)
public interface ComponentA {

}
```

`ComponentB.java`

```
@Component(modules = ModuleB.class)
public interface ComponentB {

}
```

`ModuleA.java`

```
@Module
public class ModuleA {
    @Provides
    @Named("LocationA")
    LocationService locationService() {
        return new LocationService(<your_params>);
    }
}
```

`ModuleB.java`

```
@Module
public class ModuleB {
    @Provides
    @Named("LocationB")
    LocationService locationService() {
        return new LocationService(<your_params>);
    }
}
```

And in your activity/service

```
@Inject @Named("LocationA") LocationService locationService;
```

or

```
@Inject @Named("LocationB") LocationService locationService;
```

Comment: This does allows me to declare the component twice with different @Named, but it does not guarantee that the objects injected in  of LocationRepositories constructors are the same

Comment: You can create a module to provide the params you need for the LocationRepos, and have the 2 components use that module. They'd have to have the same scope.